# Accessing zsh command line arguments within command

Tags: zsh

I would like to be able to access and modify positional parameters from within a zsh command. For example, given the below command:

```
$ foo bar baz
```

it would be helpful to be able to access `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` and use zsh's capabilities to modify them without typing them again. In a script, this can easily be done using [positional parameters](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Positional-Parameters), where `$0` would be `foo`, `$1` would be `bar`, `$2` would be baz, and so on. However,

```
$ echo foo $1
```

outputs `foo`, not `foo foo`. How can this be accomplished?

EXAMPLE:

As a concrete example, imagine there's a file with long filename that you need to reuse but modify, for example as an input and output to `ffmpeg`:

```
$ ffmpeg -i path/to/long/filename.original new/destination/filename.output
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            the argument I would like to reuse/reference within the command
```

Is there a way to not have to retype the first argument, so that something like the below (not functional) code can work (using `zsh` parameter expansion on `$1`, which doesn't unfortunately reference the first argument in the command)?

```
$ ffmpeg -i path/to/long/filename.original new/destination/"${1:t:s/original/output}"
```

[`zmv`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Functions/Misc/zmv) has the ability to do this sort of thing, but only for file renaming.

Comment: You did not show the full definition of `foo`. Also ensure that you are really calling that `foo` you _think_ you are calling. You could have several `foo` hanging around, with different definitions. Typing a `type foo` will show you which _foo_ gets invoked. I would expect your `echo` to output _foo bar_.

Comment: @user1934428 The example `echo foo $1` is intended to be independent, not referencing the example above it. I know I can define variables and then reference them. My question is, does zsh allow you to reference arguments within the same command, and if so, how?

Comment: One possibility is to use the variable assignment expansion:  `print ${a::=foo} $a` will output `foo foo`. But that has a lot of syntactic overhead; it's really only useful in some specific situations. You may have better luck with `a=foo; b=bar; print $a $b $a $b`.

Comment: I don't understand what _reference arguments within the same command_ means. Can you write a tiny example program, just leaving out the parts you don't know, and describe the desired effect (with concrete input data)?

Comment: @user1934428 Sure, no worries. I added an example that I hope clarifies things. Thanks!

Comment: I would write this as `i=path/to/long/filename.original; ib=${i##*/}; ffmpeg -i "$i" new/destination/"${ib//original/output}"`. No reason to do obscure, baroque, or shell-specific things here. (That said, with the clarification this looks more like an interactive shell use question, not a scripting question; the former is better fit to [unix.se] -- for example, the equivalent ksh and bash functionality is all under the general heading of history expansion, which is off-by-default in scripts and thus not relevant for SO's scripting/development-centric scope)

Comment: If you already know how to do it if the information were on a positional parameter (`$1`), just store the full path of the original file into a variable, and then do the exact same replacement as you gave as example, just with the variable name in place of `1`.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks everyone! Sorry for not putting it at Unix & Linux - I debated about it and chose wrong.